# UDP for interprocess communications

Tags: sockets, udp, ipc

I have to implement IPC mechanism (Sending short messages) between java/c++/python process running on the same system. One way to implement is using socket using TCP protocol. This requires maintain connection and other associated activities. 
Instead I am thinking of using UDP protocol which does not requires connection and I can send messages.
My question is , does UDP on same machine ( for IPC ) still has same disadvantage has it is applicable when communicating across machines ( like un reliable packet delivery, out of order packet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, is still unrealiable. For local communication try to use named pipes or shared memory

Edit:

Don't know the requirements of your applications, did you considered something like MPI (altough Java is not well supported...) or, Thrift? ( http://thrift.apache.org/ )

Answer (score 1):

Local UDP is still unreliable, but the major advantage is UDP multicast. You can have one data publisher and many data subscribers. The kernel does the job of delivering a copy of the datagram to each subscriber for you.

Unix local datagram sockets, on the other hand, are required to be reliable but they do not support multicast.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand this. Are you saying UDP multicast is reliable than plain UDP ?. Also is it good idea to use UDP multicast on loop back  interface to achieve cross process pub/sub with-in machine boundary.

Comment: UDP is unreliable no matter whether unicast, multicast or broadcast. There is nothing wrong with multicast on the loopback interface.

Comment: Can you please explain why UDP is unreliable for IPC. As it never leaves the host system it should not face problems like congestion, bit errors etc. Then why it is unreliable?

Comment: @Tahlil Because the send/receive socket kernel buffers have finite sizes. Fast producer or slow consumer can overflow the buffers and the kernel will start dropping datagrams.

Answer (score 1):

Local UDP is more unreliable than on a network, like 50%+ packet drop unreliable.  It is a terrible choice, kernel developers have attributed the quality down to lack of demand.

I would recommend investigating message based middleware preferably with a BSD socket compatible interface for easy learning curve.  A suggestion would be [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) which includes C++, Java and Python bindings.

Comment: I evaluated Zeromq earlier, it perfectly fits the need. But it requires additional library dependency both java ( jar ) and c++ ( lib ). I wanted to use the existing API in java and C++ to achieve the same. Also wanted to ask about UDP packet loss, do you have some data or article , so that I can better understand, why UDP communication is unreliable with in the same machine

Comment: Nothing to hand on UDP I apologize, for ZeroMQ & Java you would have to write your own native version if you don't want the JNI library.

Comment: @Steve-o Could you explain how Local UDP is more unreliable than on a network? What additional obstacles on Local in addition to those on the network?

Answer (score 0):

Local UDP is both still unreliable and sometimes blocked by firewalls. We faced this in our [MsgConnect](http://www.msgconnect.com/) product which uses local UDP for interthread communication. BTW MsgConnect can be an option for your task so that you don't need to deal with sockets. Unfortunately there's no Python binding, but "native" C++ and Java implementations exist.